# Creating a table that displays img using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have to create a page with a table that contains two columns and 10 rows. On the left column it must display the name of the country and on the other it must display the country's flag. I have to use Javascript for this page, but I don't have an idea on how to put it together. 
Here is what I have (is probably very wrong):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
    <title>New Items</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var img1 = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "argentina.jpg";
    var img2 = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
    var img3 = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
    var img4 = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
    var img5 = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
    var img6 = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "argentina.jpg";
    var img7 = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
    var img8 = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
    var img9 = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
    var img10 = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Flags</h1>
<form action="#" name="Flags" method="get">
<table style="border: 0; width: 100%;">
<tr>
    <td>
    <select name="flags" multiple="multiple"
        style="height: 98px">
        <option onclick="document.productImage.src=img1">
    Argentina</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="news" cols="30" rows="10"
    style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select name="flags" multiple="multiple"
        style="height: 98px">
        <option onclick="document.productImage.src=img2">
    Australia</option>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="news" cols="30" rows="10"
    style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select name="flags" multiple="multiple"
        style="height: 98px">
        <option onclick="document.productImage.src=img3">
    Bolivia</option>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="news" cols="30" rows="10"
    style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select name="flags" multiple="multiple"
        style="height: 98px">
        <option onclick="document.productImage.src=img4">
    Cuba</option>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="news" cols="30" rows="10"
    style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select name="flags" multiple="multiple"
        style="height: 98px">
        <option onclick="document.productImage.src=img5">
    Finland</option>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="news" cols="30" rows="10"
    style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select name="flags" multiple="multiple"
        style="height: 98px">
        <option onclick="document.productImage.src=img6">
    France</option>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="news" cols="30" rows="10"
    style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select name="flags" multiple="multiple"
        style="height: 98px">
        <option onclick="document.productImage.src=img7">
    Italy</option>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="flags" cols="30 rows="10"  
    style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select name="flags" multiple="multiple"
        style="height: 98px">
        <option onclick="document.productImage.src=img8">
    Peru</option>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="flags" cols="30" rows="10"
    style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select name="flags" multiple="multiple"
        style="height: 98px">
        <option onclick="document.productImage.src=img9">
    Syria</option>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="flags" cols="30" rows="10"
    style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <select name="flags" multiple="multiple"
        style="height: 98px">
        <option onclick="document.productImage.src=img10">
    Tunisia</option>
    </td>
    <td>
    <textarea name="flags" cols="30" rows="10"
    style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>

</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help I have spent many hours into it and my text book doesn't give any examples with img.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of improvements that can be made to your code. In no particular order, I see

**1)** All text areas have the same inline-style applied. In that case, you can remove all of that extra bloat, swapping all those 10 statements for a single 1 contained in the style tags.
So,

```
<textarea name="flags" cols="30" rows="10"
 style="background-color: Transparent"></textarea>
```

becomes

```
<textarea name="flags" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Also, add the rule to the Style section:

```
textarea
{
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

**2.** You can make use of the Image object.
You make multiple calls to `document.createElement('image')` - this can be replaced with `new Image;`

**3.** everything is hard-coded - You don't seem to be making any use of loops at all. You could store your list of countries and their flags in an array. You could then process this array, spitting-out table rows as needed. So, you could use a function that created the DOM for each row, taking 2 variables - the image path and the country name.

Here's a working example of some changes in approach: http://jsfiddle.net/AfBwJ/